# in_array() and objects comparison

Tags: php, arrays, object

I want to add an object to an array of objects only if it's not already in the array (I don't want clones).
My code doesn't work.

```
$roleCount = 0;
$roles = Array();

foreach ($result as $row) {

    // create a new Role

    $role = new Role();
    $role->setId($row['role_id']);
    $role->setName($row['roleName']);

    // add $role to $roles only if it's different from those that already are inside $roles array

    if (!in_array($role, $roles)) {
        print_r($role); // This is for test purposes
        $roles[$roleCount] = $role;
        $roleCount++;
        echo "new role added ";
    }
```

I thought that `in_array` loose comparison should have worked, but it doesn't seem to.

I read on the [object comparison page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) that

> Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.

So, why doesn't my code work? It adds the same role more than once, even if its properties are the same of the role already in the array.

**Note:** `print_r($role)` outputs this:

```
Role Object ( [id:Role:private] => 55 [name:Role:private] => user [description:Role:private] => [services:Role:private] => Array ( ) )
Role Object ( [id:Role:private] => 55 [name:Role:private] => user [description:Role:private] => [services:Role:private] => Array ( ) )
```

so it seems that objects properties are the same. Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess a better question would be why do you have duplicate IDs in whatever storage you're keeping the roles? If you're using a database, a `PRIMARY KEY` on the ID column should solve your problem.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I don't have duplicate IDs on db, I'm iterating over a result of a JOIN query in a many to many relationship (so I've got multiple references to the same role).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: Use the role's ID as a key to the array (IDs *are* unique, **right??**)

```
$roles = Array();

foreach ($result as $row) {

    // create a new Role

    $role = new Role();
    $role->setId($row['role_id']);
    $role->setName($row['roleName']);

    // add $role to $roles only if it's different from those that already are inside $roles array

    if (!array_key_exists($role->getId(), $roles)) { //Check if ID already exists as an array key.
        $roles[$role->getId()] = $role;
        echo "new role added ";
    }
```

I'm assuming `Role` has a `getId()` method, if not, `$row["role_id"]` would work just fine as well.

Comment: It worked :) But why didn't `in_array()` worked as I expected? Isn't it supposed to check if objects properties are equal?

Comment: @KurtBourbaki: It does. http://3v4l.org/CcjLK. It's possible that you have other differences. Note that **all** of the properties on both objects must be identical. (as in, `===` identical).

Comment: I edited my question. The properties of the two `$role` objects seem to be identical. Could the problem be due to the fact that properties are private?

Comment: I answer to myself: changing properties visibility in `Role` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The role's ID is different, therefore not equal.

You may want to keep an array of role *names*, rather than trying to compare objects.

Comment: `role_id` is not different, it's the same (it's just a column of a row in my db). I need an array of objects because I've got to pass it to a `User` object :)